# R - How to add 3 additional dates in my dataframe?

Tags: r

I currently have a dateframe that ends on 2019-11-30. I'd like to add 3 additional days at the bottom of the dataset [i.e. last date should now show 2019-12-03 while qty_purchased for these dates should show as 0. How can I do this?
Thanks.

[image]

--
Adding dput here:

```
structure(list(`Actual date` = structure(c(17897, 17898, 17899, 
17900, 17901, 17902), class = "Date"), qty_purchased = c(5, 
1, 2, 6, 6, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You can use `tibble::add_row(mydf, Actual_date = c("2019-12-01", "2019-12-02", "2019-12-03"), qty_purchased = c(0, 0, 0))`

Comment: @Phil Thanks. As the date col was in date format, I wrapped it around the as.Date newdf <- tibble::add_row(olddf, `Actual date` = as.Date(c("2019-12-01", "2019-12-02", "2019-12-03")), qty_purchased = c(0, 0, 0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `rbind`:

```r
df <- structure(list(`Actual date` = structure(c(17897, 17898, 17899, 
                                           17900, 17901, 17902), class = "Date"), qty_purchased = c(5, 
                                                                                                    1, 2, 6, 6, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                       "tbl", "data.frame"))
new <- data.frame(`Actual date`=seq(as.Date('2019-12-01'),as.Date('2019-12-03'),by=1), qty_purchased = 0)
colnames(new) <- colnames(df)
rbind(df,new)

#>   Actual date qty_purchased
#> 1  2019-01-01             5
#> 2  2019-01-02             1
#> 3  2019-01-03             2
#> 4  2019-01-04             6
#> 5  2019-01-05             6
#> 6  2019-01-06             8
#> 7  2019-12-01             0
#> 8  2019-12-02             0
#> 9  2019-12-03             0
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `tidyr::complete` to fill all the missing dates.

```
df <- tidyr::complete(df, `Actual date` = seq(min(`Actual date`), 
         as.Date('2019-12-03'), by = 'day'), fill = list(qty_purchased = 0))

df
```

This will create a sequence of dates from the minimum date in the dataset till `'2019-12-03'`, if a date is already present nothing happens. If the date is missing it will be added with `qty_purchased` as 0 value.